# Beginner Js : REST API returns "undefined" on successful call

Tags: javascript, rest

```
    {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.responseType = "text";
var response = XMLHttpRequest.responseText;
  request.send();
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = response;
}
```

What could be my mistake? I am trying to print the response as text but it simply says "undefined"

Comment: I also tried request.onload but that does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to listen for response data by`onreadystatechange`

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why do we use this?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest (XHR) objects to interact with servers. You can retrieve data from a URL without having to do a full page refresh. This enables a Web page to update just part of a page without disrupting what the user is doing